# Can someone explain Singletons in Magento?

Tags: magento, singleton

Ive read tons of threads on here and google and for some reason I still dont really understand what singletons are in relation to Magento. For example I created an observer that listens for an order save event and does some custom logic. Per the advice I received in another thread I have my class as singleton. How do I know this is correct? Could it be something other than singleton?

```
 <frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
            <observers>
                <reducesetinventory_save_order_observer>
                    <class>MyModule_ReduceSetInventory_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </reducesetinventory_save_order_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
<global>
    <models>
        <myname_reducesetinventory>
            <class>MyName_ReduceSetInventory_Model_Observer</class>
        </myname_reducesetinventory>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: What did the other thread say about why to use a singleton?

Comment: Observers are instantiated using `Mage::getModel()` or `Mage::getSingleton()`. "disabled" is also a option for configuration.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/making-use-of-magento-getsingleton-method/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If model was already instantiated singleton will return the instance, otherwise it will create a new one. Quite handy because in some cases you don't want to create another instance to be created (e.g. config, order, quote etc).

Answer (score 2):

From http://codemagento.com/2011/04/observers-and-dispatching-events/ :

> `<type>` - I have always used singleton, but other options can be
>   "model" or "object". The "singleton" will create the object as
>   Mage::getSingleton() while both "object" and "model" will use
>   Mage::getModel() when creating the observer object.

So, in case of singleton if your observer is called several times during script execution, you can save ("cache")  some data in private/protected variable on first observer call and use it on next call(s). For example, you can cache results of some big query, external webservice call response, etc.

Comment: The question is not only in saving system resources. In some cases creating another object instance will break the logic (for instance core/session).